# How to remove a corrupted Trust Settings Record?

Tags: security, keychain

I was trying to add a trusted cert using `security add-trusted-cert -d ...`, but somehow the Trust Settings Record became corrupted. I can see this whenever I try to add another trusted cert, or when dumping trust settings:

```
$ sudo security dump-trust-settings -d
SecTrustSettingsCopyCertificates: The Trust Settings Record was corrupted.
```

I tried restoring the keychain from backup, and then deleting the login keychain completely, but I still get the error. This makes me think the trust settings are stored in another db or something.
Any ideas on how I can delete all the trust settings?

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the Admin trust settings. It's in a file called `Admin.plist`
in the `/Library/Security/Trust Settings` directory. Deleting this file cleared the error!

There are other files in that directory that are named `<UUID>.plist`, where UUID is the value of the `GeneratedUID` key in the user record. You can see this value with this command:

```
dscl . cat /Users/<short login name> GeneratedUID`
```

These files store the per-user trust settings.

Comment: Thanks! I was following a SignalR tutorial (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website&view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code), and ran into this error. On the console, I got: "warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35] No XML encryptor configured. Key {...} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.", and in Chrome, an error that the connection wasn't secure. The steps in the article to gen dev certificate didn't work until I deleted Admin.plist. Thanks again!